# WPF initialize object in code behind and use that object in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to initialize object in xaml.cs code behind and then use that object in my binded viewmodel. But when I do that the object properly initialize, but viewmodel acts like it's still null.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<oxys:PlotView x:Name="dataPlot" Model="{Binding DataPlotModel}" Margin="10,10,185,39"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
MainWindowViewModel viewModel;

public MainWindow()
{
    viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    InitializeComponent();

    PlotModel DataPlotModel = new PlotModel();
    dataPlot.Model = DataPlotModel;
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public PlotModel DataPlotModel { get; set; }
```

And the `DataPlotModel` in viewmodel is always null unless I initialize it strictly in viewmodel.

Comment: I dont think this is the issue. When I initialize PlotModel in viewmodel everything works fine (View update the plot itself). I've tried to add         `public PlotModel DataPlotModel
        {
            get { return _dataPlotModel; }
            set
            {
                _dataPlotModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataPlotModel");
            }
        }
        private PlotModel _dataPlotModel;`
But still nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `DataPlotModel` property of the view model somewhere:

```
MainWindowViewModel viewModel;

public MainWindow()
{
    viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    InitializeComponent();

    viewModel.DataPlotModel = new PlotModel(); //<-- Set the view model property
}
```

You should set the view model property rather than setting the property of control directly as this will break the binding.

Comment: I've tried this also but with no result. But when I combine it with @ASh suggestion to raise PropertyChanged event, everything is working just how I wanted. Thanks!